# How to capture indefinite number of parameters in Express Route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Say I have an express route that takes numbers, adds them all up and returns the total.

Normally I would do something like this

```
app.get('/add/:num1/:num2/:num3', (req, res) => {
   // access and parseInt these values from req.params
   // do operations
   // return total
})
```

In this case, however, the number of parameters the route can handle is limited to 3 (or however many url parameters I hard code). What if I wanted to handle an indefinite or unknown number of parameters? In this case, numbers?

Ultimately I want the route to be able to handle 2, 3, 5, 10, or 20 numbers if that's what the user sends.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Express route supports * wildcard . You can get all the numbers using '*'

```
app.get('/add/*', (req, res) => {
   const paramsArray = req.params[0].split('/');      
    // req.params[0] contains all the params separated by '/'
    // split the params using split function and it will return an array containing all parameters 

})
```

This array can be used to iterate over params.

e.g req.params[0] for *`GET /add/1/2/4/6`* will return `1/2/4/6` and after splitting using split function it will be `[1,2,4,6]`. And finally add operation can be done on elements of array.